# webBrowser setAttribute

Tags: c#, browser, web

Here is the problem

```
<input type='text'name='TextBox0001'/>
```

For example to insert a value for the input of above is just by using this code :

```
foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("TextBox0001"))
{
he.SetAttribute("value", "HI");
}
```

That's okay but how do I insert a value for the counter if the html code written like below?

```
<table>
<tr id='set1_row1'>
<td> <input type='text'name='counter'></td>
</tr>

<tr id='set1_row2'>
<td> <input type='text'name='counter'></td>
</tr>
</table>
</table>
```

I am using c#  webBrowser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "set1_row1" would be:

```
foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("counter"))
{
    if(he.Parent.Parent.getAttribute("id") == "set1_row1")
    {
        he.SetAttribute("value", "HI");
    }
}
```

You get the idea, so you can figure out your exact logic based on this example.